# Какую базу данных выбрать для работы с деревьями?

Tags: база-данных, структуры-данных, дерево

Нужна БД, которая умеет хранить и работать с деревьями (например, обходить деревья вглубину). На sql это будет не очень удобно делать, так как эта БД про другое. Есть ли популярные какие-нибудь решения?

Comment: Что такое деревья, в вашем понимании? Приведите пример того что вы хотите хранить и как, и, еще хорошо бы, пояснение вам не подошел SQL.

Comment: @Kromster например, я хочу обходить деревья вглубину. На sql это будет не очень удобно делать.

Answer (score -1):

По-моему все прекрасно хранится в обычной sql базе.. типа дерево это структура данных с 3 ячейками памяти - данные, ссылка на левого ребенка и на правого ребенка. 
У вас будет таблица всего с 4 колонками: Id и описанные выше ячейки, только вместо ссылок будете хранить Id листа.
Другой вопрос в скорости обхода.. реляционные бд как ни оптимизируй, вытягивают 10-15 запросов в секунду, для обхода масштабного дерева это мало, посмотрите в сторону какой нибудь  NOSQL системы которая используется для хранения кеша, типа Redis или MongoDB

Comment: Я знаю про редис и монгу. Они про другое. И ваш ответ повторяет мой вопрос. Скорее всего будет neo4j